# I want to perform client side validation using jquery in struts 2 forms. Can some one give me a reference so that i can start doing my validation?

Tags: jquery, struts2

I want to perform form validation in java using jquery, i 've using struts 2 framework. I'am new to jquery, so is there is any site that tells me how to do??

Comment: I have done sever side validation, but stuck in the client side!!:(

Comment: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Comment: Binay , if any of the answers help you out here, then upvote and accept them .

Comment: @TheDarkKnight yeap! i surely will..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to perform user side validation I reccomand [jquery validation plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation)

Comment: Wow!! As i am new to jquery.. This site helped me alot..Thanks @strongBAD

Answer (score 1):

Well I'm no struts expert, but if it works anything like HTML and if it supports JavaScript it should work like this.

```
var elementBeingTested = $("#textElementID").val();

if (elementBeingTested != null) {

}
```

Comment: only a null check in forms is not enough. One might need a lots of validations. Its better to use jquery validator plugins.

Comment: I'm new in jquery, so i really don't know what the above code does, but any ways thanks for you sugeestion:)

Comment: @Binay : If you do not understand something then tell us what you are not understanding. People here will help you out on everything

Comment: This is a better answer as compared to the others who are suggesting to use a plugin. Using a separate plugin for simple client side validations is not a good idea. Writing your own code for such validations gives you more power and control over the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You can type form validation jquery in google. It will return hundreds of results. Any ways, you can use this [link](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation#Validate_forms_like_you.27ve_never_been_validating_before.21) . Its one of the oldest ways to validate forms.

**"You need to place error messages in the DOM and show and hide them when appropriate. You want to react to more than just a submit event, like keyup and blur. You may need different ways to specify validation rules, based on the server-side enviroment you are using on different projects"**

If want to do any specific client side validation, you can use this [link](http://code.google.com/p/bvalidator/).

**"bValidator is a jQuery plug-in for client side form validation. It supports fully customized error messages defined with template and CSS, many validation functions (actions) like date, email, URL, IP address, validation of dynamic forms, customized validation functions and more."**

Comment: I the link http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation what does the src in <script> denotes??

Comment: I have searched in many sites,but the think is that the src(source) in script tag is always different

Comment: the src is actually source, what it means is that when you give src = url, it points out the url where your resource is , either a javascript(js) file or a css(cascading style sheet) file .

Answer (score 0):

Oh, this is pure jquery queston :) Use [Jquery Vlidation plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation)
Download it [from here](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) and use it simle like this:

```
<form id="myform">
  <input type="textfield" name="field1" class="number"/>
  <input type="textfield" name="field2" class="required"/>
</form>

<input type="button" onClick="$('#myform').validate()">
```

So validation plugin will check that field1 is number or empty and field2 is not empty.